# Unable to display flash message in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and using expressjs framework,Right now i want to display "flash-message" ,But right now i am getting following error message

```
req is not defined
```

Here is my controller

```
async function handleSignup(req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    try {
        const user = await UserModel.createUser(username, password); // Assuming you have a Model to handle data
        req.flash('success', 'User registered successfully!');
        res.redirect('/'); // Redirect to a signup.ejs
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Error creating user'); // Handle error
    }
}
```

Here is my views(signup.ejs)

```
<% const successMessage = req.flash('success'); %>
<% if (successMessage && successMessage.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="flash-message success">
        <%= successMessage %>
    </div>
<% } %>
...//further code
```

Comment: I don't think req.flash exists

Comment: You've given irrelevant code. Let's work from the error. What do you do that triggers the error?

Comment: Flash is not Node.js but a custom library

Comment: @Itamar kindly tell me how can i display flash message ? what is wrong with my code

Comment: Which package is your intention [express-flash-message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash-message) or [flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flash) or [Express Flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash) or some other flash package? There are numerous others with similar API's but different implementations.